# How to retrieve the opacity value within a mixin

Tags: css, sass, mixins

So I have the following problem, I want to be able to select a row in a table, and when I do that row gets an active background color. So far no problems. However, if the user should specify the background color to be transparent or set the opacity in rgba()-string to 0 then I want to display the underlaying row-color.

Now if I use a mixing I could style my css in different ways. But how can I get the opacity from the rgba-string to determine whether the string should be transparent or not? Does regex work within a mixin?

I.e.: I would something like (I know, the regex part is js but somthing similar for css/mixin):

```css
@mixin active-background-color($activeBackgroundColor){ 
 @if ($activeBackgroundColor.replace(/^.*,(.+)\)/,'$1') == 0) { 
  background-color: none;
 } @else {
        background-color: $activeBackgroundColor
    }
}
```

So the solution turned out to be the following (should anyone be interested):

```css
@mixin active-background-color($color) {
    $alphaVal: alpha($color);
    @if ($alphaVal== 0){
      background-color: inherit;
    } @else {
      background-color: $color;
    }
}
```

Link to the solution I used: [The Sass Way](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/mixins-for-semi-transparent-colors)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should simply define the selection on the tr
and add the user picked color to the td:

```
tr { background-color: whitesmoke; }     //  default row color                  
tr:hover    { background-color: #ccc;  } //  default row selected color
tr:hover td { background-color: tomato } //  user defined selected color
//  if the user selects a transparent selection color
//  the default row selected color will show
```

```css
table { width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;}
tr { cursor: pointer; }
td { font:1rem sans-serif; padding:.2rem; }

tr { background-color: whitesmoke; }                       
tr:hover    { background-color: #ccc;  }                   
tr:hover td { background-color: tomato }                   
tr:last-of-type:hover td { background-color: transparent }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>One</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Two</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Three</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: I do appreciate you taking your time answering my question, but I found the answer I was looking for here: http://thesassway.com/intermediate/mixins-for-semi-transparent-colors

I just needed some more digging. But, thank you very much again anyways.